# On the complex function $f(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sigma(n)^{-s}$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, divisor-sum, analytic-continuation

Let $s=x+iy$ the **complex variable** (if you want a difffernt notation you are welcome), then I know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$ **converges** for $\Re s>1$. On the other hand let $\sigma(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d$ the **sum of divisors function**. An important fact is that $\sigma(p)=p+1$ if and only i $p$ is a **prime number**. We define for some **abscissa of convergence** $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(\sigma(n))^s}.$$
Since applying the **triangle inequality** one has $$\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(\sigma(n))^s}\right|\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{|\sigma(n)^s|}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sigma(n)^{\Re s}},$$
and one knows that $\sigma(n)\geq n+1>n$ for each $n>1$ (notice that $\sigma(1)=1$) then $(\sigma(n))^{-\Re s}<n^{-\Re s}$ with convergence of the infinite series thus for $\Re s>1$ by the **comparison test**. And since $\sum_{p \text{ prime}}1/p$ diverges (thus by comparison also $\sum_{p \text{ prime}}1/(p+1)$) **I believe that the abscissa of convergence is** $1$ (please if there is some mistake or inaccurancie in my claims say me, I want learn and write mathematics rigurously).

Thus the information that I can deduce for this function is that has a **pole** at $s=1$ and converges in the half-plane $\Re s>1$. But I don't know what different claims can be deduced easily.

> **Question.** I would like to learn more about complex analysis, what's about this function $$f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(\sigma(n))^s}$$
>   concerning if  is it **meromorphic**, (I hope that my words and claims are rights), **it is possible**/feasible **an analytic continuation** to different regions of the complex plane, or can you deduce other easy things about **non-vanishing** for $\Re s>1$...? Has **zeros**?

Thus I am asking about what's things are easily deduced for a complex function of this kind. I understand that is a question involving a lot of possible computations, but I would like to know how works with this kind of functions from the complex path. You can deduce the more relevant facts and other provide us as hints.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: I hope that someone encourage to answer some about this question, because I believe that it is nice and this is the best site to share your knowledges. I have a lot of questions (some nice and other very bads!) but I want learn more. Thanks.

Comment: Nice question. The language and terminology you used are properly correct. A nice question would be whether there exists something analogous to Euler's product formula.

Comment: Thanks for your words. I am asking a lot of questions because 
I do not want to leave to study mathematics. This is the best site since I encourage myself to study more. On the other hand my deductions are using comparisons. Very thanks much @Crostul , then feel free to study, explore and ask about yourself question.

Comment: Many thanks @Did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function extends meromorphically to $\Re(s)>0$ (with a single pole of order $1$ at $s=1$), and has at least the same zeroes as the Riemann zeta function does there.

Indeed, by using multiplicativity it follows that for $\Re(s)>1$ we have the following formula:

$$f(s) = \prod_{p} (1+\frac{1}{\sigma(p)^s}+\frac{1}{\sigma(p^2)^s}+...)$$

This is already enough to see that this function has no zeroes for $\Re(s)>1$: by using $\sigma(p^k) > p^k$, one shows this each factor is $1+O(\frac{1}{p^s})$, and each factor is non-zero. Such fast-converging products are known go arrive at a non-zero value.

Let me first show the how to extend it for $\Re(s)>1/2$, and the general extension will follow from a more careful analysis. Because $\sigma(p) = p+1$, and  $\frac{1}{(p+1)^s} = \frac{1}{p^s} + O(\frac{1}{p^{s+1}})$ each factor is equal to:

$$1 + \frac{1}{p^s} + O(\frac{1}{p^{2s}})$$

(notice that the contribution of the powers of $p$ is at most $O(1/p^{2s})$, which dominates $\frac{1}{p^{s+1}}$ for $s<1$).

Now divide this function by the zeta function and use the zeta function Euler product to get that for $\Re(s)>1$:

$$\frac{f(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \prod_p(1+\frac{1}{p^s}+O(p^{2s}))(1-\frac{1}{p^s}) = \prod_p(1+O(\frac{1}{p^{2s}}))$$

However this product is defined and is holomorphic (and non-zero) not only for $\Re(s)>1$, but for $\Re(s)>1/2$, so the ratio $\frac{f(s)}{\zeta(s)}$ is holomorphic there, so $f$ extends holomorphically to that region and has the same zeroes and poles as $\zeta$ there.

One can show in fact that the factors of the ratio between $f$ and $\zeta$ satisfy:

$$(1-\frac{1}{p^s})(1+\frac{1}{\sigma(p)^s}+\frac{1}{\sigma(p^2)^s}+...) = 1+O(\frac{1}{p^{s+1}})$$

Which converges absolutely for $\Re(s)>0$, giving the desired extension.

I would be interested in hearing about further extensions of $f$ or reasons to expect there are none.

Comment: Yours is a very nice answer. I am going to study the details, and thus I should check yours as an answer of my question in next hours. Additionally many thanks for your attention in my question, and feel free to ask about your last statement, as yourself question in these sites Stack Exchange.

Comment: I just noticed that the extension actually works out for $\Re(s)>0$ - I have added this to the solution.